# How to multithread stored procedure calls in java from an array list?

Tags: java, multithreading, stored-procedures, callable-statement

I currently have a java program that runs a single stored procedure call one record at a time from an array list that loops through until all records are processed.  It is taking about 8 seconds per record to return from the stored procedure call currently.  After it finishes the call it takes the XML message from the SP and continues on in the code to write that message to the queue and then updates a field in the database to mark the record as processed.

What I would like to do is have x amount of threads hit/call the stored procedure at once to speed up the processing time of the full array list and continue through the other steps as it does now.  The array list can be anywhere from a few hundred records to upwards of 4000.

Is there a way to still go through the same process after the call, but add multithreading to hit the SP multiple times at once without everything running into each other causing issues?  I've only been coding for a short period of time so please bear with me, thank you!

```
public void callStoredProcedure(){

    Connection conn = null;
    DSConnection dsc = new DSConnection();

    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    /*
     * stored procedure LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER
     * 
     *  in_company IN NUMBER,
        in_PO_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2,
        in_po_release IN NUMBER,
        in_po_code IN VARCHAR2,
        in_object_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
        RET_CODE OUT NUMBER,
        RET_MSG OUT CLOB)
    */

    ArrayList<YmpohdroutDbo> PurchOrderList = new ArrayList<YmpohdroutDbo>(getInsertUpdatePurchOrders().values());

    try {

        //conn = dsc.getConnection();

        ProcedureResult res;

        for(int i=0;i<PurchOrderList.size();i++) {

            conn = dsc.getConnection();

            // calling SP   
            callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{ call "+PurchaseOrder.dbProperties.getProperty("Schema") +".LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

            // register input fields of SP
            callableStatement.setInt(1, PurchOrderList.get(i).getCompany());
            callableStatement.setString(2, PurchOrderList.get(i).getPO_Number());
            callableStatement.setInt(3, PurchOrderList.get(i).getPO_Release());
            callableStatement.setString(4, PurchOrderList.get(i).getPO_Code());
            callableStatement.setString(5, (PurchaseOrder.projProperties.getProperty(Constants.SEC_KEY_COMMENT_TYPE))); 

            // register output fields of stored procedure 
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(7, java.sql.Types.CLOB);

            // execute LWN_XML_PURCHASEORDER SP
            callableStatement.execute();

            res = new ProcedureResult();
            res.setCode(callableStatement.getInt(6));
            res.setMessage(callableStatement.getClob(7));

            // send response from SP to MQ
            PurchaseOrder.writeClobMQMessage(res.getMessage());

            // mark record as processed 
            markRecordAsProcessed(PurchOrderList.get(i), conn);

            DSConnection.close(conn, null, callableStatement, null);
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        if (callableStatement != null) {
            try {
                callableStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            DSConnection.close(conn, null, callableStatement, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: " it takes the XML message from the SP ": what is SP? can we see XML message  in your program code?

Comment: The stored procedure (SP) returns an XML string, which we send to our messages queue.  The XML is generated in the stored procedure outside of the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start several threads, each executing the same method callStoredProcedure. The only change is to move PurchOrderList out of callStoredProcedure to make it common for all threads, and convert it to a queue instead of ArrayList.

UPDT this is a particular case of the Producer-Consumer pattern with single producer who fills the queue and several consumers which take items (records) from the queue.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!  Do you happen to have a good example of this?  I can't seem to find something similar to what I'm trying to do.